# one 'serving' of sugar - a person serving sugar?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_packet

> A sugar packet is a delivery method for **one** 'serving' of sugar.

Does **one** there mean a person?

Comment: It's "one" as in a single measure or portion of sugar.

Comment: If it meant a person, the rest of the sentence would plain not parse. Person serving *of sugar what?* It makes no sense. One [*serving*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/serving) is one portion.

Comment: It means the number half-way between zero and two.

Comment: For some verbs in English, the verbal noun (in _-ing_), as well as meaning the act of doing the verb, can also mean a (specific) result of doing the verb. So _leavings_ can mean _things left behind_, an _opening_ is _a hole left open_, and _a serving_ is _a portion served_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example it means a small amount of sugar, suitable for usage by one person.

> [serv·ing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/serving)  [sur-ving]   noun
>   *a single portion of food or drink*

A **sugar server** would be a person serving sugar.

Comment: I take two servings of sugar in my coffee

Comment: It's suitable for usage by one person, but obviously only half-suitable in your case!